# Problema al Imprimir Datos de una Matriz C++

Tags: c++

Buenas Tardes, tengo el siguiente ejercicio en el que pido Nombre, Cedula, y ademas la cantidad de forros producidos diariamente, pero hay que tomar en cuenta tambien que se debe hacer por semana (asumiendo que el mes tiene 4 semanas).

**El programa funciona de la siguiente manera:**

Pido el Nombre y Cedula del Trabajador, luego por cada dia de la semana (5 dias), le pido cuantos forros ha producido, cuando termine la primera semana, **debe imprimir el reporte semanal**, luego pasaria a hacer lo mismo pero con la semana 2 y asi sucesivamente, cuando termine con ese trabajador que pase al siguiente.

Como esta actualmente el programa, hace todo bien hasta que llega a imprimir el reporte semanal, es ahi donde me imprime el nombre y la cedula, pero los otros datos no los imprime y de paso aparece el mensaje "Ha Dejado de Funcionar...".

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
char nombre[9][30];
int cedula[9];
//int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
int i, a, b, c;
const float sueldo = 15000, bono = 8250;
float forro_dia[5][5];
float total_semana[5];

for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese el Nombre del Trabajador: "<<i<<". ";
    cin.getline(nombre[i], sizeof(nombre));
    cout<<"\nCedula del Trabajador: ";
    cin>>cedula[c];

    for (int a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
    {              
        for (int b = 1; b <= 1; b++)
        {
            cout<<"\nCantidad de Forros Producidos en el Dia: "<<a<<". "<<"de la Semana: "<<b<<". "; 
            cin>>forro_dia[a][b];

            total_semana[b] = total_semana[b] + forro_dia[a][b];

            if (forro_dia[a][b] >= 80)
            {
                total_semana[b] = sueldo + bono;
            }else

                total_semana[b] = sueldo;

        }

    }

        system("cls");
        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
        cout<<"< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";
        cout<<"\n\n< = = R E C I B O  S E M A N A L = = >";
        cout<<"\n\nTrabajador: "<<nombre[i];
        cout<<"\nCedula: "<<cedula[c];
        cout<<"\nForros Producidos en la Semana: "<<forro_dia[a][b];
        cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<total_semana[b];

        getchar();
        getchar();

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: cout<<"\nForros Producidos en la Semana: "<<forro_dia[a][b]; esta afuera de cualquier ciclo.. que valores tiene a y b?

Comment: Es una Matriz. Arriba esta declarado como float forro_dia[5][5];

Comment: Para serle sincero no lo he mirado mucho tras ver esto "<=" pero le puedo decir que usted esta haciendo uso de `forro_dia[a][b];` o `total_semana[b];` cuando `int i, a, b, c;` no estan inicializada pues la `b` a la que me imagino que usted piensa que hace referencia esta fuera ya de su scope `for (int b = 1; b <= 1; b++)`. podria usar `for (b = 1; b <= 1; b++)` pero eso le traera otros errores pues aunque no entre en el for por la condicion, esta si se suma con lo que tendria que restarla cuando la use despues, recomiendo que busque otra manera de hacerlo, y mirar como fucionan la indexacion.

Comment: en los arrays por ejemplo al principio de este texto -> https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C%2B%2B/Arrays_y_cadenas_de_texto entendiendo eso puede hacer uso de "<" en lugar de "<=" y empezar desde 0 no desde 1 a mirar en el array o a añadir, **que la memoria no la regalan** (broma). Saludos

Comment: por otro lado si se le complica la cosa que quiere hacer con los for a la hora de mostrar los datos puede leer sobre metodos/funciones e intentar usarlas en su codigo. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, sin embargo no doy todavia con la solucion.

Answer (score 3):

Complementando la respuesta de gbianchi:

-Cuando se escribe un for de la forma

```
   for (int a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
```

Se está declarando la variable a dentro del For, por lo que no es necesario su declaración en la parte superior de tu código.
Por otro lado, Deberías iterar de ésta manera

```
for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
```

Empezar desde el cero hasta el numero que pretendes llegar, ya que los arreglos y matrices en los lenguajes de programación, comienzan con índice cero. Por lo que estás dejando un espacio vacío al empezar en la posición 1.

Comparto la opinión de gbianch, Imprimir los valores semanales debería estar dentro de un nuevo for para moverte dentro de la matriz y corroborando que el valor de los índices sea coherente.

Comment: de esa forma vas a imprimir los titulos en cada iteracion, vas a borrar la pantalla a cada rato, y no va a ser lindo, por eso no aclare mas, ya que OP no aclaro que quiere...

Comment: Yep... tenes razón...
Edito

Answer (score 2):

#### Problema.

Nos encontramos ante un claro ejemplo de los problemas que pueden surgir al tener un código mal organizado. En tu caso, la función `main` tiene tanta información que hace que sea más complicado de lo necesario analizarla.

El problema parece estar ya resuelto por las pesquisas de [gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/65716/2742) y [federhico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/65718/2742) pero yo quisiera compartir una aproximación adicional.

#### Propuesta.

Te aconsejo seguir el [Principio de responsabilidad Única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica): separa el pintado de cabeceras de la obtención de datos y la presentación de los mismos.

Para ello empezaremos por definir una estructura de datos que contenga la información del trabajador:

```
struct Trabajador
{
    std::string nombre;
    int cedula;
};
```

He escogido `std::string` como tipo para almacenar el nombre del trabajador porque de esta manera evitamos que tenga una longitud fija; en tu caso estabas limitando el nombre del trabajador a 9 caracteres (8 si contamos el carácter nulo de finalización de cadena) así que un trabajador llamado `"Teodoredo"` ya no te cabría<sup>1</sup>.

Seguimos con una función que, dado un trabajador, lea sus datos:

```
void leer_datos(Trabajador &trabajador)
{
    std::cout << "\n\nIngrese el Nombre del Trabajador: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, trabajador.nombre);
    std::cout << "\nCedula del Trabajador: ";
    std:: cin >> trabajador.cedula;
}
```

A continuación, una estructura que almacene la producción de una semana y nos devuelva datos sobre la misma:

```
struct Semana
{
    float produccion[5u]{};

    float forros() const
    {
        return std::accumulate(std::begin(produccion), std::end(produccion), 0.f);
    }

    float total_a_pagar(float sueldo, float bono) const
    {
        float resultado = 0.f;
        for (const auto &produccion_dia : produccion)
        {
            resultado += (sueldo + (produccion_dia < 80.f ? 0.f : bono));
        }
        return resultado;
    }
};
```

He asignado la responsabilidad de calcular los salarios en base a datos de la semana a la propia semana, pero puedes escoger otra aproximación.

Con esta estructura podemos crear una función que, dada una semana, lea sus datos:

```
void leer_datos(Semana &semana)
{
    for (auto dia = 0u; dia < 5u; ++dia)
    {
        std::cout << "\nCantidad de Forros Producidos en el Dia: " << (dia + 1) << ". "; 
        std::cin >> semana.produccion[dia];
    }
}
```

Para acabar, parece que necesitamos una estructura `Recibo`:

```
struct Recibo
{
    Trabajador trabajador;
    Semana periodo[5u];
};
```

Que podemos leer con esta función:

```
void leer_datos(Recibo &recibo)
{
    leer_datos(recibo.trabajador);
    for (auto semana = 0u; semana < 5u; ++semana)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\nSemana " << (semana + 1)<< ".\n";
        leer_datos(recibo.periodo[semana]);
    }
}
```

De esta manera puedes tener un `main` tan limpio como este:

```
int main()
{
    Recibo recibos[9u];

    std:: cout << "< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";

    for (auto &recibo : recibos)
        leer_datos(recibo);

    std::cout << "\n\n< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";
    std::cout << "\n< = = R E C I B O  S E M A N A L = = >";

    for (const auto &recibo : recibos)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\nTrabajador: " << recibo.trabajador.nombre
                  << "\nCedula: "       << recibo.trabajador.cedula;

        for (auto semana = 0u; semana < 5u; ++semana)
        {
            std::cout << "\nForros Producidos en la Semana " << (semana + 1) << ": " << recibo.periodo[semana].forros()
                      << "\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. " << recibo.periodo[semana].total_a_pagar(15'000.f, 8'250.f);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Y si añadimos los apellidos, nuestro amigo *Teodoredo Atanagildo-Gundemaro de las Mercedes* queda fuera del todo.

Comment: Bueno, primero agradecido. Luego el nombre[9] y cedula [9], es por que son vectores, los necesito almacenarlos asi porque luego de esto debo hacer un menu y de alli sacar varias opciones, en las que se incluye lista de los trabajadores. En este caso la cantidad de forros producidos diariamente debe almacenarse en una matriz (una matriz para cada semana), como haria en ese caso? Estoy un poco confundido.

Answer (score 1):

Fijate que todo el ciclo de impresion no esta inicializado ni esta recorriendo los items de la matriz

```
    cout<<"\n\n< = = R E C I B O  S E M A N A L = = >";
    cout<<"\n\nTrabajador: "<<nombre[i];
    cout<<"\nCedula: "<<cedula[c];
    cout<<"\nForros Producidos en la Semana: "<<forro_dia[a][b];
    cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<total_semana[b];
```

Toda esta parte, esta afuera de los ciclos for donde cargaste los datos. con lo cual solo va a imprimir los datos de una persona.

Aunque esa fuera tu intencion, a y b los usaste en los ciclos for, y al llegar a esas lineas tienen valores por fuera de los intervalos de la matriz (por que asi los dejaron los ciclos for).

No se entiende bien tu intencion, pero deberas declarar los valores correctos de a y b o pasar posiciones de matrices validas.